# How to detect the offset in a digital signal?

Tags: algorithm

Currently I am writing an algorithm to detect the offset in the values from ADC. An example of a typical signal is as shown in the figure below.
[image]
There can be a possibility that such a signal can have an offset at any point of time due to the external conditions. An example is as shown in the figure below.
[image]

I would like to determine this exact point when an offset is added to the signal.

**Approach I have tried**:

Calculate the moving average of around 50 values and compare it to the old mean value. If the difference is too large then conclude that there is an offset.

**Problem with this approach**: It also considers the peak in the signal as the offset which is not really the case.

The offset has to be detected in real time. I am currently coding in C.

I have spent almost a week trying to figure out the solution, but as a last way out I am asking you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem in signal processing, known as step detection:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_detection

There are many algorithms to deal with the problem, you will have to do some research and whichever algorithm you decide to go with, you will probably have to do some parameter tweaking before it suits your needs. I would recommend starting with the sliding window algorithm for your needs, a sample implementation of student's t test can be found [here](https://github.com/wjakob/hypothesis/blob/master/hypothesis.h), perhaps you can build on that.